# How can I add a row number at each grouping header in .rdlc report?

Tags: c#, reporting-services, grouping, rdlc, row-number

I have problem when I try to add row number for each group parent group ("Group1") which have child group ("group2","group2")using RowNumber Function with group scope Like that `=RowNumber("Group1")` group with the previous Function  I get the report like that :?

parent group :Row No:2  Group1: 1   value child group2

```
                                  1  value 
                                  2   value
```

parent group :Row No:4  Group1: 2   value child group2

```
                                  1  value 
                                  2   value
```

parent group :row No:5  Group1: 3   value child group2

```
                                  1  value
```

parent group :row No:6  Group1: 4   value child group2

```
                                  1  value
```

parent group :row No:8  Group1: 5   value child group2

```
                                  1  value 
                                  2   value
```

> But i need it like

parent group :Row No:1  Group1: 1   value child group2

```
                                  1  value 
                                  2   value
```

parent group :Row No:2  Group1: 2   value child group2

```
                                  1  value 
                                  2   value
```

parent group :row No:3  Group1: 3   value child group2

```
                                  1  value
```

parent group :row No:4  Group1: 4   value child group2

```
                                  1  value
```

parent group :row No:5  Group1: 5   value child group2

```
                                  1  value 
                                  2   value
```

I also try to use `RowNumber(Nothing)` but its not give me the result I want,

> Any help Thanks...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

by using that expression in head group I Solved the problem :

```
runningvalue(Fields!YourParent_GroupName.Value,countdistinct,nothing)
```